# How To Capture Picture using react-native-camera

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

I try capture image using react-native-camera, but it's failed,
hire my code.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You are accessing "this" in the functional component

Class level component:

```
takePicture = async () => {
    if (this.camera) {
      const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true };
      const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
      console.log(data.uri);
    }
  };

<RNCamera
          ref={ref => {
            this.camera = ref;
          }}
          style={styles.preview}
          type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
          flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on}
          androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
            title: 'Permission to use camera',
            message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
            buttonPositive: 'Ok',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}
          androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{
            title: 'Permission to use audio recording',
            message: 'We need your permission to use your audio',
            buttonPositive: 'Ok',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}
          onGoogleVisionBarcodesDetected={({ barcodes }) => {
            console.log(barcodes);
          }}
        />
```

For functional component

```
const cameraRef = useRef();

takePicture = async () => {
      const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true };
      const data = await cameraRef.takePictureAsync(options);
      console.log(data.uri);
  };

<RNCamera
          ref={cameraRef}
          style={styles.preview}
          type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
          flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on}
          androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
            title: 'Permission to use camera',
            message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
            buttonPositive: 'Ok',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}
          androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{
            title: 'Permission to use audio recording',
            message: 'We need your permission to use your audio',
            buttonPositive: 'Ok',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}
          onGoogleVisionBarcodesDetected={({ barcodes }) => {
            console.log(barcodes);
          }}
        />
```

Comment: it's work
const data = await cameraRef.current.takePictureAsync(options);